# Google Cloud Shell - Cannot open shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I am really new to Google Cloud Shell, and I accidentally closed the tab for the shell...and I cannot find it now.

I know I need to click the highlighted button at the top of the console window to activate Google Cloud Shell, but it is now grey, and no shell is presented on the page (it should be at the bottom). [image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: I can't repro - whenever I close the shell's window the button reactivates. Things you could try: reloading the page, opening the developer console in a new window, logging out your google account and logging back in, restarting your browser.

Answer (score 3):

I observed the same issue.
I refreshed the console page ( CTRL + F5 ) and I was able to see the 'Activate Cloud Shell' button again !!

However, if above does not resolves the issue, some tips:

From google docs [Google Cloud Shell Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations)

> Weekly usage: Cloud Shell also has weekly usage limits. If you reach
>   your usage limit, you'll need to wait until the specified time (listed
>   under Usage Quota, found under the three dots menu icon) before you
>   can use Cloud Shell again.

Also, there are usage limits on this, check your email if you had violated any conditions on shell usage:

> Warning: Violating the Terms of Service will result in Cloud Shell
>   being disabled for your account. This constitutes activity that
>   adversely impacts Google Cloud Platform services, other customers' or
>   their end users' use of services, or the Google network used to
>   provide these services. Coin mining and network scanning using Cloud
>   Shell are strictly prohibited.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue here.
You can install the command line interface in your terminal to access Google Cloud Datalab.
Here you will find the quickstart to configure the environment.

Installing datalab component:

```
gcloud components install datalab
```

Connecting with your VM Instance:

```
datalab connect *instance-name*
```

Opening the initial page:

```
http://localhost:8081
```

See more:
[Google Cloud Datalab - Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstart)

Comment: Datalab is not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It works now. It seems that there was a service problem earlier today, so the page was not well functioning.